# How to create a branch before committing to master

Tags: git

Considering that I may not want to commit anything to the master branch in a brand-new project, how can I create a feature branch before committing anything to master?

```
  git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/brandon/Code/some_project/.git/
  git branch some_feature
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
```

I'd like to do all my work in feature branches, and merge them in when they're ready.  It does not appear to be possible to do this *from the very beginning of a project*.  Is there a way to do it without committing garbage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is possible, but not with the command : `git branch <my-branch>`

But you can with :

```
git init
git checkout -b some-feature
```

git checkout -b will create a branch and switch to it automaticaly

Answer (score 2):

```
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/pat/foo/.git/
$ git checkout -b foobar
Switched to a new branch 'foobar'
```